Does spinning the umbrella slow down the fall more?
Ignoring its structural weakness, if you jump from some height and use an umbrella to slow down the fall, would making it spin while you're falling affect the speed in any way?

why do you think it would?

Because a spinning object, like a plane propeller, is supposed to move air differently than a non-rotating one.

a propeller has blades which are specifically designed to create thrust parallel to the axis of rotation. An umbrella does not.

But it should nonetheless affect in some way, right? I mean, if it's rotating, maybe the air below is being dissipated outwards?

If doing this is on your skydiving itinerary, please tell the medical community whether it’s the fall or the sudden stop that kills you, because you’re certainly going to find out. That is, no, it won’t work.
Umbrellas are like parachutes, except their surface area for air deflection is very small and they break very easily. Even if you had some sort of super-rigid ultra-strong umbrella, it couldn’t possibly make a meaningful dent in your terminal velocity.
Spinning it won’t help. Aircraft and propellers and all those things behave interestingly when spinning - sometimes resulting in lift or thrust - because they have surfaces specifically angled and shaped to produce certain airflows. No such umbrella exists, and the more you modify the concept of “umbrella” to try and produce more lift when held or even spun, the more it turns into a helicopter.
It would sort of act like a really poorly-designed propeller because of its shape, but its blade profile would actually push you down because of the angle (or if you somehow managed to get it to push you up, it wouldn’t be by nearly enough to be meaningful).

No, of course I know it won't act like a parachute, I just wanted to know if spinning it would accelerate the fall or slow it down and why.

Also, how do you know it would push you down? How do its angles define that?

Just the shape of the umbrella. The fringes, pointing down, would deflect air upwards, which creates thrust downwards. And accelerating it would hardly make a meaningful differences is my point.
